# Is it possible to merge or integrate wordpress website with a normal website?

Tags: php, wordpress, web-testing

I am trying to build my own personal website.

i want to implement a blog system and a photo gallery in my website.

i just imagined about the website and I want to complete my site by myself.

suppose, I have created a normal HTML website.

now, I want to start blogging with WordPress on that website.

sorry for my weak English.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. There are various ways to approach it. But they're all going to have some level of complexity that might be beyond a "total newbie". Might be easier to just use WordPress and move your existing content into it?

Comment: No, this is impossible....  Just kidding, all you have to do is setup wordpress in a folder (sub directory) and in the link from your existing site, point to that folder.  Then backlink to the org site from within the wordpress site.  Basically Wordpress will be running in a sub folder inside your existing site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to run WordPress in a sub-folder.

On you site we'll add a folder named `wp` (just for example).  Install WordPress in this folder.

I'm not sure of the steps but in the  Settings General tab you need to make sure the URLs there have your subfolder in them.

And you may need to modify the htaccess  (RewriteBase ) too.

Basically you have your HTML site, and in that you link to the folder `wp` then when a user navigates to `www.example.com/wp` they are running the wordpress install in that folder.  Then you just backlink to the HTML link, like with a site logo or Home link in the menu or such.

Simple.

Comment: this is my site: http://paran360.com
and I want to start blogging here : http://paran360.com/blog.html